# Convert String.CharacterView.Index to int

Tags: swift

How can I convert titleRange to an Int!?

```
var text: String = "Another neat aspect of playgrounds and the Assistant Editor is that you can inspect the output at different points in the program 
flow. So for instance, you could add another view of the UILable to the 
Assistant Editor before you’ve applied the changes to background color and 
corner radius to see what it looks like before that. Just click on the little white circle next to the “UILabel” to the right of the line where you’d like to inspect. "


let titleRange = Int(text.characters.indexOf( "." )) //Convert to Int!

var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text as String)
attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: titleRange))
```